# How to evaluate part of an expression using macros in C?

Tags: c, macros

I am currently developing a unit test library in C and I wanted to add a functionality Catch (in C++) had.
When you do, using Catch :

```
int x = 5;
REQUIRE(x == 4);
```

The output will be something like this :

```
Failed statement : x == 4
     evaluated as 5 == 4
```

Is it possible to do something like that in C ?
This needs to be done at runtime.

Comment: `static_assert`?

Comment: `static_assert` is in C++, isn't it ?

Comment: It was added to `assert.h` in C11.

Comment: I forgot to specify it needs to be done at RunTime, my bad. But static_assert will not work with a variable like `x` in my example.

Comment: How exactly does your requirement differ from what `assert()` provides?

Comment: @EOF Catch will evaluate the parts of the expression. Kievh: the answer is: it can't be done. Not really.

Comment: I suspect OP's problem is that `assert()` will only tell you that `x` wan't `4`, not what it actually was.

Comment: You need to do it the traditional way: have a separate ASSERT_XXX macro for each operator...

Comment: Remember that expressions and variables exist only at *compile* time; at runtime they have vanished. C is not an homoiconic language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this. It's not very convenient, but it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ASSERT_INT 1
#define ASSERT_EQ(x,y,type) do { if((x)!=(y)) {     \
        switch(type) {                 \
        case ASSERT_INT:               \
            printf("Failed statement : %s == %d\n\tevaluated as %d == %d\n", \
                   #x, (y),(x), (y)); break;                            \
        } exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }} while(0)
```

It requires some work though. If you want many operations you can do like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ASSERT_INT 1
#define ASSERT_EQ 1
#define ASSERT(x,y,op,type) do {                                        \
        int success;                                                    \
        char op_str[3];                                                 \
        switch(op) {                                                    \
        case ASSERT_EQ:                                                 \
            strcpy(op_str, "==");success = ((x) == (y)); break;         \
        }                                                               \
        if(!success) {                                                  \
            switch(type) {                                              \
            case ASSERT_INT:                                            \
                printf("Failed statement : %s %s %d\n\tevaluated as %d %s %d\n", \
                       #x, op_str, (y),(x), op_str, (y)); break;         \
            } exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }} while(0)
```

And the output:

```
$ ./a.out 
Failed statement : x == 4
    evaluated as 5 == 4
```

You will need to add a modified version of `strcpy(op_str, "==");success = ((x) == (y)); break;` for each different logical operation and a modified version of `printf("Failed statement : %s %s %d\n\tevaluated as %d %s %d\n", #x, op_str, (y),(x), op_str, (y)); break;` for each different type.

Comment: Thanks, it is not really what I hopped though, but I think I am too demanding on that. `op_str` can be replaced by `#op` and directly enter `(x) op (y)`, but I do not know how to remove the type variable, which is the only real problem left. Thanks once again !